# Column added only works for first row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, dynamic-columns

I am displaying my columns dynamically for my GridView and I want to add another column based off the values from two other columns. So the new column is the number of Jobs minus the number of POD. I was able to create the new column but it is only displaying results for the first row in the GridView and all the other rows are blank. Also is it possible to change the position of this column? It defaults to the last column but I would like it to be the 4th column in the GridView.

```
main.Columns.Add("NotPOD", typeof(int));
              int index = 0;
              foreach (DataRow row in main.Rows)
              {
                  main.Rows[index]["NotPOD"] = Convert.ToInt32(main.Rows[index]["Jobs"]) - Convert.ToInt32(main.Rows[index]["POD"]);
              } 

            gvResults.DataSource = main;
            gvResults.DataBind();
```

Comment: Your index is not updating

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid how do I change the position of the column?

Comment: use `DisplayIndex` Property

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid I tried adding the code `main.Columns["NotPOD"].DisplayIndex = 5;` but it causes the error does not contain a definition for DisplayIndex

Comment: No, Its for `DataGridView`, You can use `SetOrdinal` for `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bug. When you use foreach, you have no need to use index. You also did not increment index

```
      foreach (DataRow row in main.Rows)
      {
          row["NotPOD"] = Convert.ToInt32(row["Jobs"]) - Convert.ToInt32(row["POD"]);
      }
```

Comment: thanks it worked. Do you know how to change the position of the column?

Comment: You mean in main? or gridview?

Comment: in the gridview. Main is the name of the DataTable and gvResults is the name of the gridview

Comment: After data bind to the gridview, you can use displayindex to change order.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I moved `main.Columns["NotPOD"].DisplayIndex = 5;` after the bind code but I get the error does not contain a definition for DisplayIndex

Answer (score 2):

Using `foreach`

```
main.Columns.Add("NotPOD", typeof(int));    
foreach (DataRow row in main.Rows)
{
   row["NotPOD"] = Convert.ToInt32(row["Jobs"]) - Convert.ToInt32(row["POD"]);
} 
gvResults.DataSource = main;
gvResults.DataBind();
```

Using `for`

```
main.Columns.Add("NotPOD", typeof(int));    
for(int index = 0;index < main.Rows.Count; index++)
{
   main.Rows[index]["NotPOD"] = Convert.ToInt32(main.Rows[index]["Jobs"]) - Convert.ToInt32(main.Rows[index]["POD"]);
} 
gvResults.DataSource = main;
gvResults.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a problem to resolve it update your index as

```
main.Columns.Add("NotPOD", typeof(int));
          int index = 0;
          foreach (DataRow row in main.Rows)
          {
              main.Rows[index]["NotPOD"] = Convert.ToInt32(main.Rows[index]["Jobs"]) - Convert.ToInt32(main.Rows[index]["POD"]);
              index++;
          } 

        gvResults.DataSource = main;
        gvResults.DataBind();
```

I hope it will help you